# Matching pursuit algorithm using Gabor dictionary

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dictionary, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to implement Matching Pursuit algorithm in Matlab and suddenly I got this doubt. This algorithm selects the atom from a pre-defined gabor dictionary which gives a maximum inner product with the signal. What happens if there are two atoms that gives the same maximum inner product value?
Which atom will this algorithm select?

Comment: Often such choices are made arbitrarily.

Comment: so is it normal that there will be more than one atom which will give the same value in this algorithm?

Comment: I do not think "same" is well defined for real numbers. Double precision floats, although only an approximation, will differ with a very high likelihood. If you are getting exact match, then probably you have a duplicate function (down to a linear transform) in your dictionary.

Comment: @kkm I'm not getting an exact match. But can I assume that this condition will never happen in MP algorithm with any dictionary. Or is there a possibility that this might happen?

Comment: You won't be wrong selecting any of the two. I would just trust the `max()` function and forget that there might be two or more very close matches.